# change domain of JSESSIONID cookie in Apache

Tags: apache, cookies, jsessionid

Currently JSESSIONID is set by xxx.domain.com and I'd like to read the JSESSIONID from yyy.domain.com, so how can I change the JSESSIONID cookie's domain from xxx.domain.com to .domain.com? I'm using Apache as web server. Thanks.